# Replace gcc 13 with self-compiled gcc 12.2 in Fedora 38?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, fedora

I've compiled (`make` + `make install`) from sources gcc 12.2 into `/usr/local/gcc12`.

Now `gcc --version`:

```
gcc (GCC) 13.0.1 20230401 (Red Hat 13.0.1-0)
Copyright (C) 2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

List `/usr/local/gcc122`:

```
bin  include  lib  lib64  libexec  share
```

`/usr/local/gcc122/bin`:

```
drwxr-xr-x. 1 root root       676 Apr 25 22:25 .
drwxr-xr-x. 1 root root        60 Apr 25 22:25 ..
-rwxr-xr-x. 4 root root   5705624 Apr 25 22:25 c++122
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root   5701800 Apr 25 22:25 cpp122
-rwxr-xr-x. 4 root root   5705624 Apr 25 22:25 g++122
-rwxr-xr-x. 3 root root   5695360 Apr 25 22:25 gcc122
-rwxr-xr-x. 2 root root    145976 Apr 25 22:25 gcc-ar122
-rwxr-xr-x. 2 root root    145880 Apr 25 22:25 gcc-nm122
-rwxr-xr-x. 2 root root    145888 Apr 25 22:25 gcc-ranlib122
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root   5697728 Apr 25 22:25 gcov122
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root   3484168 Apr 25 22:25 gcov-dump122
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root   3660344 Apr 25 22:25 gcov-tool122
-rwxr-xr-x. 2 root root   5706568 Apr 25 22:25 gfortran122
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 249334728 Apr 25 22:25 lto-dump122
-rwxr-xr-x. 4 root root   5705624 Apr 25 22:25 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-c++122
-rwxr-xr-x. 4 root root   5705624 Apr 25 22:25 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-g++122
-rwxr-xr-x. 3 root root   5695360 Apr 25 22:25 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc122
-rwxr-xr-x. 3 root root   5695360 Apr 25 22:25 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc-12.2.0
-rwxr-xr-x. 2 root root    145976 Apr 25 22:25 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc-ar122
-rwxr-xr-x. 2 root root    145880 Apr 25 22:25 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc-nm122
-rwxr-xr-x. 2 root root    145888 Apr 25 22:25 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc-ranlib122
-rwxr-xr-x. 2 root root   5706568 Apr 25 22:25 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gfortran122
```

`./gcc122 --version`:

```
gcc122 (GCC) 12.2.0
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

How can I replace installed default gcc 13 to gcc 12.2 (`/usr/local/gcc12`) correctly (Last step after long stage make)?

Rebooting did not help.

Answer (score 1):

Why rebuild old software that's been compiled a million times? I agree it should be a simple addition to `alternatives` but as it's so core maybe not. Make sure to get the right version. For now F37 still has 12.3.1. Otherwise select the version you need directly.

```
dnf --releasever=37 --installroot=/tmp/yourdir gcc
export PATH=/tmp/yourdir/usr/bin:$PATH
```

Not ideal, but https://www.phoronix.com/news/F32-Update-Alternatives-CC

Comment: I get `No such command: gcc. Please use /usr/bin/dnf --help`, do you mean `dnf --releasever=37 --installroot=/tmp/yourdir install gcc`, that seems to work.

Comment: Although I don't like to mess with PATH, this seems the most straightforward way to get gcc 12 in Fedora38/39. I hope it doesn't mess up the repositories.

Answer (score 0):

When you type `gcc` it will run the first `gcc` command in your `$PATH`.  You can use `type -p gcc` to see what that is, but usually it will be `/usr/bin/gcc`, which will actually be a symlink to some specific version of gcc.  So you can can change that symlink to point somewhere else (a different version of gcc) to change it globally.

I believe redhat has an `alternatives` command just for managing symlinks like this, so you may be able to use it to see all the versions you have installed and select between them.